# ASP.NET Core Web API return status code + object

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-codes

For ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API :

What is the best practice on returning an async result that contains a compound result :

1. JSON representation of object/collection ( T or IEnumerable )
2. HttpStatusCode

Comment: Action filter we can use I guess.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#action-filters

Comment: Do you mean you want to return a custom model like Task<T>? Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

May be, that's something what you needed.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<SOMETYPE> Get()
{
    return StatusCode(200, SOMEOBJECT); 
}
```